# Issue after publish MVC .net Website - Compilation Error

Tags: compiler-errors, iis-7, windows-server-2012

After I publish my website to IIS on Windows Server 2012, I had the error below.

Before this, I publish in my own localhost, via IIS 7.0, and it works.

[image]

Someone can help me?

Comment: Have you checked the logs?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem (code -2146232576) excluding from my project references, reference to MICROSOFT.NET.COMPILER and MICROSOFT.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.

Published again and magically it works.